# Assistance with a regular expression Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to achieve this regular expression check. (1 integer, 3 digits)

Valid:

- 0.236
- 0.21
- 1.231
- 1.01

Invalid:

- 12.23
- 12321
- 0.21323

I would like to have only 1 digit follow by a decimal with only 0-3 decimal places.

Any help would be great. I have tried this:
`^(([0-9]{1})?(?=\.)[0-9]{0,3})|([0-9]{1})$`
but no lock.

Edit: I should have added that I'm using a JQuery plugin called inputmask. I would like for the inputmask to only accept my requirement.

Comment: @Tushar: That would match two-thirds of his "invalid" examples.

Comment: Will your number be inputted by itself.  Will there be any other text?  Are these valid: `$1.23`, `0.325`, `some text 1.23`?

Comment: Don't rename the question to include the word "SOLVED", see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have only 1 whole number follow by a decimal with only 0-3 decimal places.

By "1 whole number" I take it you mean one *digit*, as `12` is a single whole number. If so:

```
\d\.\d{0,3}
```

That matches a single digit followed by a `.` followed by zero to three digits. If you want to further assert that it matches the *entire* string, add anchors to either end:

```
^\d\.\d{0,3}$
```

Note that the rules you've given allow for `1.`, which seems like you may not want. If you don't, then we need to do a *bit* more work:

```
^\d(?:\.\d{1,3})?$
```

That says: One digit *optionally* followed by a `.` with 1-3 digits. It has the "whole string" anchors, remove them if you don't want them.

**Live Example** using that last one:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var rex = [
  /\d\.\d{0,3}/,
  /^\d\.\d{0,3}$/,
  /^\d(?:\.\d{1,3})?$/
];
input.oninput = input.onpaste = input.onkeypress = updateDisplay;

function updateDisplay() {
  rex.forEach(function(r, index) {
    var display = document.getElementById("r" + index);
    if (!input.value) {
      display.innerHTML = "--";
    } else if (input.value.match(r)) {
      display.innerHTML = "valid";
    } else {
      display.innerHTML = "INVALID";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<p><code>/\d\.\d{0,3}/</code> says: <span id="r0"></span></p>
<p><code>/^\d\.\d{0,3}$/</code> says: <span id="r1"></span></p>
<p><code>/^\d(?:\.\d{1,3})?$/</code> says: <span id="r2"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried all three but still doesn't work. Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using a plugin called "inputmask". I would like to only allow the user to type in 1 digit, decimal and 0-3 digits.

Comment: @user3407584: I had a typo at the beginning of the third one. The regexes definitely work, see the live example.

Comment: You should accept this answer. He beat me to the punch by a few minutes. I think it's better than mine anyway.

Comment: @user3407584: Alternately, if you found Richard's explanation more useful, accept that one. "First" need not mean "best." :-)

Answer (score 1):

To do this with `jquery-inputmask`, use this

```
<input id="example2" data-inputmask-regex="/^\d{1}\.\d{0,3}$/" />
```

And then in your JavaScript file, add this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#example2").inputmask("Regex");
});
```

Here is the Regex breakdown

`^` - Regex must start with this expression

`\d{1}` - Exactly 1 digit from 0 to 9

`\.` - Followed by a period. Important to note that periods must be escaped

`\d{0,3}` - Followed by 0 to 3 digits

`$` - Regex must end with this expression

I tested for all of your examples.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to upvote but since I'm new, it wouldn't allow me to do so. :(